# How can I find the number of comparison operations for a qsort()?

Tags: c

How can I find out the number of comparison operations for a qsort?

I have an array of pointers that should be sorted.
This array of pointers points to an array of structures.

```
struct oristru {
    char string1[TITLE_FIELDLENGTH];
    char string2[AUTHORS_FIELDLENGTH];
    short int 1;
};


const struct oristru oristrukts[] = { ...}

const struct oristru *temp_oristru[ARRAYLEN(oristrukts)];
struct oristru *p_sortst[ARRAYLEN(oristrukts)];

qsort(*p_sortst, ..);
```

Comment: You are providing `qsort` with a comparison function. So tweak it so it will increment some static counter each time it is called..

Comment: `short int 1;` does not seem correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you're sorting with function `fx()`

```
qsort(..., fx);
```

just tweak `fx()`

```
// global var to count comparisons
unsigned long ncomp = 0;

int fx(const void *a, const void *b) {
    ncomp++;
    /* return ...; */
}
```